# Python merges 4 digit hex to 3 digit hex

Tags: python, hex, byte

I'm trying to send some bytes from Python. I'm using `struct.pack` to get the corresponding sending bytes. For example:

```
>>> struct.pack('BBBBBh', 200, 0, 56, 6, 0, 6)
'\xc8\x008\x06\x00\x00\x06\x00'
```

If you take a close look, you can see that the second byte (that sould be `\x00`) has been merged with the next byte (that should be `\x38`).

In fact, if I try to concatenate by text:

```
>>> '\x00' + '\x38'
'\x008'
```

The same thing happens.

I need to have `'\x00\x38'`. Is this possible? Am I missing something related to formats or whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a byte is a printable character, Python will print it instead of its hexadecimal value.

0x38 (decimal 56) is the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) for the character `'8'`, therefore  `'\x00\x38'` is printed as `'\x008'`.

If you want to print the hexadecimal values for all bytes, you have to do it explicitly, for example:

```
print(['{:02x}'.format(b) for b in data])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it was printing the character 8.